# agregar datos de una tabla distinta a la que ya tengo en mi consuta sql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Hola amigos de Stack Overflow. Me gustaría una respuesta con información o documentación asociada para poder comprenderlo en detalle, ya que es algo para el mundo profesional.

Resulta que obtengo datos de una BD filtrados por año y mes, en donde los datos se agregan automaticamente con mysqli_fetch_assoc().

Ahora necesito que se muestre una nueva fila en la misma matriz, pero con valores tomados desde otra tabla de la misma BD.

```
$conexion = new conexion();                         // instanciar coneccion.

$anio = $_GET['Ganio'];                              // peticion $_GET a formulario y almacenamiento en variable $anio para posterior procesamiento de datos (año)
$mes = $_GET['Gmes'];                                // peticion $_GET a formulario y almacenamiento en variable $mes para posterior procesamiento de datos (mes)

if($mes >= 1 && $mes <= 9){
  $AnioMes = $anio.'-0'.$mes;           // si la variable mes es igual o mayor a 1 y menor o igual que 9, se agrega automaticamente un "0" a la izquierda, para mayor legibilidad.
}
else {
  $AnioMes = $anio.'-'.$mes;           // agregamos un guion (-) para separar las variables, concatenarlas, recibirlas y ejecutar el jquery
}

$SQL = "SELECT fecha, despacho_kilos, despacho_pesos, indaval_kilos, indaval_pesos, arco_kilos, arco_pesos FROM ventas_stgo WHERE fecha  LIKE '%{$AnioMes}%' LIMIT 0,50"  ;  //consulta SQL con filtro de fechas.

$result = mysqli_query($conexion->conectarse(), $SQL);

$valores = '<table id="tabla" class="datatableresult" name="tabla" border="1" style="float:left;">
<thead>
<tr class="enunciado2">
  <td rowspan="2" colspan="1" width="100">
      <div style="font-size:12px">Fechas</div> </td>  <td rowspan="1" colspan="2" width="200">
      <div style="font-size:12px">Despachos</div>
  </td>
  <td rowspan="1" colspan="2" width="200">
      <div style="font-size:12px">Stock Recibido INDAVAL</div>
  </td>
  <td rowspan="1" colspan="2" width="200">
      <div style="font-size:12px">Stock Recibido ARCOCHILE</div>
  </td>
    <td rowspan="1" colspan="2" width="200">
      <div style="font-size:12px">Diferencias</div>
  </td>
  <td colspan="6" rowspan="2" width="100">
      <div style="font-size:12px">Dias H&aacute;biles</div>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr class="enunciado2">
  <td colspan="1" width="100">
    <div style="font-size:12px">Kilos</div>
  </td>
  <td colspan="1" width="100">
    <div style="font-size:12px">Pesos</div>
  </td>
  <td colspan="1" width="100">
    <div style="font-size:12px">Kilos</div>
  </td>
  <td colspan="1" width="100">
    <div style="font-size:12px">Pesos</div>
  </td>
  <td colspan="1" width="100">
    <div style="font-size:12px">Kilos</div>
  </td>
  <td colspan="1" width="100">
    <div style="font-size:12px">Pesos</div>
  </td>
    <td colspan="1" width="100">
        <div style="font-size:12px">Kilos</div>
    </td>
    <td colspan="1" width="100">
        <div style="font-size:12px">Pesos</div>
    </td>
</tr></thead><tbody>';

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))   //mientras que la variable $result siga obteniendo valores, creara celdas y filas necesarias dentro de una tabla asignando los valores solicitados en la columna $row, desde la bd.
  {


    $valores = $valores."<tr>";

    $valores = $valores."<td>".$row['fecha']."</td>";

    if($row['despacho_kilos'] >= 0) {                           //si el valor de la variable es negativo el color de la fuente sera rojo, destacando cifra en contra.
    $valores = $valores."<td>".$row['despacho_kilos']."</td>";
  }
    else {
    $valores = $valores."<td style='color:red;'>".$row['despacho_kilos']."</td>";

  }

    if($row['despacho_pesos'] >= 0) {                         //si el valor de la variable es negativo el color de la fuente sera rojo, destacando cifra en contra.
    $valores = $valores."<td>"."$".$row['despacho_pesos']."</td>";
  }
    else {
    $valores = $valores."<td style='color:red;'>"."$".$row['despacho_pesos']."</td>";

  }
  if($row['indaval_kilos'] >= 0) {                             //si el valor de la variable es negativo el color de la fuente sera rojo, destacando cifra en contra.
    $valores = $valores."<td>".$row['indaval_kilos']."</td>";
  }
  else {
    $valores = $valores."<td style='color:red;'>".$row['indaval_kilos']."</td>";

  }

  if($row['indaval_pesos'] >= 0) {                            //si el valor de la variable es negativo el color de la fuente sera rojo, destacando cifra en contra.
    $valores = $valores."<td>"."$".$row['indaval_pesos']."</td>";
  }
  else {
    $valores = $valores."<td style='color:red;'>"."$".$row['indaval_pesos']."</td>";

  }
  if($row['arco_kilos'] >= 0) {                               //si el valor de la variable es negativo el color de la fuente sera rojo, destacando cifra en contra.
    $valores = $valores."<td>".$row['arco_kilos']."</td>";
  }
  else {
    $valores = $valores."<td style='color:red;'>".$row['arco_kilos']."</td>";

  }
  if($row['arco_pesos'] >= 0) {                                 //si el valor de la variable es negativo el color de la fuente sera rojo, destacando cifra en contra.
    $valores = $valores."<td>"."$".$row['arco_pesos']."</td>";
  }
  else {
    $valores = $valores."<td style='color:red;'>"."$".$row['arco_pesos']."</td>";

  }



    $valores = $valores."</tr>";

}

echo $valores."</tbody></table>";         //muestra los valores solicitados en el jquery, dentro de una tabla y esta dentro del tbody

 ?>

//esta es la consulta sql que me entrega el valor que necesito:
 " SELECT fecha FROM `dias_habiles` WHERE empresa = 01" 



[![en la columna dias habiles tengo que tener el resultado de la sentencia sql que muestro un poco atras.][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CoRdT.png
```

Comment: No termino de comprender tu problema. Si tenes el query y el codigo que genera la tabla, porque cuando terminas de agregar filas de un query no agregas las filas del otro?

Comment: Debes buscar el campo por el cual puedas relacionar ambas tablas. debe ser un campo en comun, del mismo tipo de datos.

Comment: Como dice @JCLXS si las tablas están bien relacionadas. Lo ideal  sería hacer una consulta anidada y en el primer query te trajeras el valor que necesitas. Más info: (https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp)

Comment: acabo de revisar, y no,  no estan enlazadas.  estoy viendo algo. les comento como me fue. y disculpen si no me expreso bien xd

Answer (score -2):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

necesitaba mostrar dias habiles de cada mes, y mostrar en una columna que dia era segun el 1ro de cada mes, entonces:

1 encontree una funcion que entrega el dia segun fecha:

```
    function saber_dia($nombredia)
    {                                                                                                               //funcion para saber el dia segun fecha
            $dias = array('Domingo','Lunes','Martes','Miercoles','Jueves','Viernes','Sabado');
              $fecha = $dias[date('N', strtotime($nombredia))];
                        return $fecha;
                            }
```

con esto se que dia es el primero de cada mes, luego cuento los dias y cuando sea viernes me suma los valores para obtener un total semanal:

***a todo esto el antiguo dev de la empresa no tenia claves foraneas ni nada y mas aun, en distintos campos "fecha" algunos estaba el mes con cero (1990-15-02) y en el que tenia que usar para traer el dato estaba sin cero.. (1990-15-2). entonces con una  funcion para obtener la fecha sin cero, contando strings xd, entonces con varias funciones en conjunto logre hacerlo. les dejo el codigo por si les sirve.

```
$obtenerMes = strtotime($row['fecha']); // CONVERTIR FECHA A UNIX FORMAT (EJEM: 100656898)
                $Anio = substr($row['fecha'], 0, 4); // MOSTRAR LOS PRIMEROS 4 DE UNA CADENA PARTIENDO DEL 0
                $filtro = date("m", $obtenerMes); // OBTENER MES A PARTIR DE UNA FECHA UNIX
                $MesSinCero = str_replace("0", "", $filtro); // ELIMINAR EL 0 DEL MES SI LO TIENE

                $fechaSinCero = $Anio."-".$MesSinCero; // APLICANDO FORMATO (Año-mes) EJEMP: 2018-1

                        // OBTENIENDO LOS DIAS HABILES DESDE BASE DE DATOS
                $sqlDiasHabiles = "SELECT diasHabiles from dias_habiles WHERE fecha = '".$fechaSinCero."'   AND empresa = '1'";
                $query = mysqli_query($conexion->conectarse(), $sqlDiasHabiles);
                $rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);

                $valores =  $valores."<td>".$vuelta."/".$rows['diasHabiles']."</td>";

                        // SUMANDO VALORES POR CADA ITERACION

                            @$kilosSemanales += $row['despacho_kilos'];  // "@" sirve para silenciar errores que no afectan el funcionamiendo del script
                            @$PesosSemanales += $row['despacho_pesos'];
                            @$kilosSemanalesI += $row['indaval_kilos'];
                          @$pesosSemanalesI += $row['indaval_pesos'];
                            @$kilosSemanalesA += $row['arco_kilos'];
                            @$pesosSemanalesA += $row['arco_pesos'];
                            @$kilosSemanalesD += $diferenciaKilos;
                            @$pesosSemanalesD += $diferenciaPesos;

                $valores = $valores."</tr>";

                        // SI ES VIERNES AGREGAR FILA CON TOTAL
                                                if(saber_dia($row['fecha']) == "Viernes"){
                $valores = $valores."
                                        <tr style='font-weight:bold; color:black; background:#FFD2D2'>
                                            <td>TOTAL SEMANAL</td><td>".$kilosSemanales."</td>
                                            <td>$ ".number_format($PesosSemanales)."</td><td>".$kilosSemanalesI."</td>
                                            <td>$ ".number_format($pesosSemanalesI)."</td><td>".$kilosSemanalesA."</td><td>$ ".number_format($pesosSemanalesA)."</td>
                                            <td>".$kilosSemanalesD."</td><td>$ ".number_format($pesosSemanalesD)."</td><td>-</td>
                                        </tr>";

                            // VOLVER VARIABLES A 0 POR CADA VUELTA DEL WHILE


                            $kilosSemanales += 0;
                            $PesosSemanales += 0;
                            $kilosSemanalesI += 0;
                            $pesosSemanalesI += 0;
                            $kilosSemanalesA += 0;
                            $pesosSemanalesA += 0;
                            $kilosSemanalesD += 0;
                            $pesosSemanalesD += 0;


                                }

                $vuelta++;

                                }
```

aparte de sumar  y recorrer las columnas tuve que idear como hacerlo y con un poco de asesoria llegue a la solucion. solo me falta sumar los totales y GG.

muchas gracias por su atencion.

Comment: estimado, con todo respeto, publico mi solucion para que gente como tu comprenda que no por saber un poco mas pueden ser intolerantes con los demas, de todos modos, tu respuesta no aporta nada.

Comment: Me alegra que pudieras resolver el inconveniente por tu cuenta, nada mas gratificante que encontrar una solucion por uno mismo. Pero, si te fijas, tu respuesta se aleja bastante a tu pregunta. En tu respuesta has proporcionado mucha mejor informacion que la pregunta por lo que era casi imposible que alguien pudiera darte una opcion, solucion o una guia. Por lo tanto no te sorprendas por lo negativos o incluso el cierre de la misma.

Comment: Se agradece un monton que quieras contribuir. Tene en cuenta un par de aspectos. Tu pregunta sigue sin comprenderse, y la respuesta no soluciona el "supuesto" problema de la pregunta, que era como agregar un dato de otra tabla en tu vista. El resto de los problemas que mencionas son raros. No se a que te referis por ejemplo con que no tenias claves foraneas. Sera que no estaban definidas como foraneas en la db? eso no es necesario si se controlan por el sistema. Es mas, en las bases de datos grandes no lo vas a encontrar en ninguna. (sigue)

Comment: Esta genial que encuentres la solucion a tu propio problema y es algo que incentivamos un monton. Pero trata siempre de que la pregunta sea clara, y la respuesta sea sobre la pregunta. Varios aspectos que mencionas en la respuesta no estan en la pregunta. Si quisieras, podrias abrir preguntas particulares para cada aspecto (por ejemplo, como obtener el dia de las semana segun una fecha). Esperamos verte mas seguido!!! y revisa [ask] y [answer]